# Open gl es 1.0 - Any way to draw a Square with a border around it?

Tags: opengl-es, lines

I've been attempting to find ways of doing this, but have had no luck thus far.

I want to just use an array of triangles to draw a square, and then I want to be able to like say the Color is black, but have a red border around it.

This possible?

Thanks!

Comment: +1 Were you able to figure this out?